# Get current location in JSplumb toolkit version

Tags: jsplumb

In jsplumb we are having the provision for managing the dataset.In that we are having nodes,edges,ports.In that edges we are having the provision of overlays.My need is when we overlay the edges i want to display content at the same location .we are having the provision to get and set the current location in community version.I am using the toolkit version.Is any predefined functions are available to get the current location(x,y co-ordinates) in toolkit version.